# Angular 2 Observable emit/error functions are ignored after calling error function once

Tags: api, http, angular, typescript, observable

I have a API login service using a http service to perform a login logic (LoginApiService, login-api.service.ts):

```
login(data: LoginCredentials): Observable<LoginResult> {
  let body = JSON.stringify( data );
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post(`${this.getBaseUrl()}/login`, body, options)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(function(error: Response){
                    return Observable.throw(error); // IF YOU TRY TO LOGIN WITH WRONG CREDENTIALS, AN ERROR WILL BE THROWN
                  });
}
```

This service is used in a global service class (authService, auth.service.ts):

```
login(data: LoginCredentials): void {
    this.api.login(data).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.group = data.group;
      this.Login.emit(new LoginResult(this.group)); // THE CALL OF THIS FUNCTION IS IGNORED IF THE "this.Login.error" FUNCTION HAS BEEN CALLED BEFORE
    },
    error => {
      this.Login.error(error); // THIS IS IGNORED TOO, IF IT WAS CALLED BEFORE
    }
  );
}
```

Component (LoginComponent, login.component.ts):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.LoginSubscription = this.authService
    .Login
    .subscribe( // THE EVENTS ARE NOT FIRED IF THE ERROR EVENT HAS BEEN FIRED BEFORE ONCE
      data => {
        if ( this.authService.isLoggedIn ) {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
}

login() {
  this.authService.login( new LoginCredentials(this.user, this.password) );
}
```

Template (login.component.html):

```
<div>
  <label>User: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="user" placeholder="user">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Password: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="password" type="password">
</div>

<p>
  <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
</p>
```

If the error event function of the login observable has been called before, calling the emit and/or error function after this will be ignored.

- With correct login credentials, the simulated API responses with HTTP
  code 200 and everything works fine
- On wrong credentials, the HTTP response is 500
- After calling the API again (with correct or wrong credentials), the
  events are not fired anymore

**This means:** If you use wrong login credentials you won't be able to try again without re-loading the page.

- Is my idea of using observables wrong?
- Why is the event stream hung up after calling the error function
  once?
- Could someone give me a hint to solve this problem (some kind of
  workaround eg.)?

Comment: It really seems, that a stream hungs up if an error occurs (at HTTP Codes like 4XX or 5XX). I don't know how to fix this issue, am I wrong or is it right, that it is not possible to use APIs like the one I described or similar approaches like mentioned in [this example](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2#ResponseCodes) with Angular 2 / Observables? I can't imagine that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are erroring out your EventEmitter.  EventEmitters are basically Observables and when it's Observer calls `error` or `complete`, it closes the Obersvable.  Closed Observables will stop emitting events by design.

To fix your problem, remove `this.Login.error(error);` in the `LoginComponent`. so that you are not closing that EventEmitter.  Try replacing that with logic to tell the user that the credentials are wrong or some other message to describe the error.